# Property 'collectionView' and 'photos' not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

So I have been using a book called "IOS in Action" for my programming and I have come across a few problems that I cannot figure out how to fix. The point of this is to have photos already in the Photos app show up in my Albums app using a viewController. The problems are:

1. Property 'collectionView' not found on object of type 'IAPhotoCollectionViewCell*'
2. Incompatible pointer types returning 'IAPhotoCollectionViewCell*' from a function with result type 'UICollectionView'
3. Property 'photos' not found on object of type 'IAPhotoCollectionViewCell*'

I am a newbie at programming so please explain why these are happening and how to fix them. Here is my code for IAPhotoCollectionViewcell.m

```
#import "IAPhotoCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "IAAlbumPhotosViewController.h"

@implementation IAPhotoCollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
return self;
}  

-(UICollectionView*)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
            cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"photoCell";
    IAPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ALAsset *asset = self.photos[indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

And here is my code for IAPhotoCollectionViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IAPhotoCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

And also for the IAAlbumPhotosViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface IAAlbumPhotosViewController : UICollectionViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ALAssetsGroup *album;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *photos;

@end
```

Thank you!

So I have tried using:

```
IAPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (IAPhotoCollectionViewCell*)[self.collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but I have get a "Property 'collectionView' not found on object of type 'IAPhotoCollectionViewCell*' I will try adding a property 'collectionView'. So I found my problem was that I didn't have a @property section for 'collectionView' and an error went away.

Comment: #1, `collectionView` is a property on `IAAlbumPhotosViewController` not `IAPhotoCollectionViewCell`. But we can't see where you're trying to use that property. #2, use a cast. #3, same as #1 but for `photos`. It appears as if you're confusing your interfaces. But I cannot see that in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry about being new but could you please give me an example of a cast

Comment: `IAPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (IAPhotoCollectionViewCell*)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why didn't you say so in your post? Make an edit that shows that, and what went wrong. Telling me "it didn't work" tells me very little.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line in my IAPhotoCollectionViewCell.h file solved the problem

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionView *collectionView
```